# Why even after fetching the data and logging it, whenever I render it to the page after reloading the application breaks in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, undefined

I am undertaking one of the projects from [frontendmentor.io](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/rest-countries-api-with-color-theme-switcher-5cacc469fec04111f7b848ca)

Whenever I click any of the mapped data, with the help of react-router-dom I am redirecting it to *url/countryName*.

In this scenario, I am using react-router-dom to fetch a particular country while using the useLocation hook to fetch the url, the problem is everything works fine in the first render but as soon as I reload the website the application breaks. No matter how many times I try it never renders again.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React,{ useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Country = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const name = location.pathname.split('/')[1]
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [country,setCountry] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountry = async() => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${name.toLowerCase()}?fullText=true`)
        console.log(res.data,res)
        setCountry(res.data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    getCountry()
  }, [name])

  console.log(country[0].name.common) // returns undefined after reload

  const backButton = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    navigate('/')
  }

  return (
    <div className='country-page page'>
      <button onClick={backButton} className='backButton'>back button</button>
      <div className='country-page-layout'>
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Country
```

Other resources:

- [error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5bud.png)
- API which I am using : https://restcountries.com/

Comment: well the countries haven't been loaded yet

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Yeah, I do notice it quite a few times. I have used async function. Is there any another way around it?

Comment: You need a loading state to solve that, like a spinner to indicate data is fetching.

Comment: @thefarerevenant just use optional changing operator here `console.log(country?.[0]?.name?.common);` it's rendered before data fetched that's why you getting this error.

Comment: @Kantivekariya It worked, thanks. I want to ask you; how did the data get fetched easily on the page where all the countries are listed whereas in this fetch it got fetched so late?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for your data to be fetched first, and then render it.

```
const [country,setCountry] = useState({})
//country is an empty object 


//but here, your are trying to get the value from the array. (But country is an empty object)

 console.log(country[0].name.common) // returns undefined after reload
```

The solution is to check if your data is here first

```
if (country?.[0]?.name?.common){
 console.log(country[0].name.common)
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I want to ask you; how did the data get fetched easily on the page where all the countries are listed whereas in this fetch it got fetched so late?

Comment: @thefarerevenant Sorry, I didn't get the notification for your comment. That site probably builds their page on server side where all the contries are already added to the html page so they don't have to fetch anything. But you are requesting their data to be sent from their API to you, and that is why it is slower.